# Pytorch model 2D regression given an scalar input

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, regression

I want to create a model to perform this regression:

[image: 2D Regression]

My dataset looks like:

```
t,x,y
0.0,-,0.5759052335487023
0.01,-,-
0.02,1.1159124144549086,-
0.03,-,-
0.04,1.0054825084650338,0.4775267298487888
0.05,-,-
```

I'm having some troubles with loss, dataset load, batch_size, and Net structure (I add one single layer to simplify the problem)

Thats my code:
Net:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    '''Model to regress 2d time series values given scalar input.'''
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        #Layers
        self.predict = nn.Linear(1, 2) 

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x
```

Dataset load

```
class TimeSeriesDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        #Load the dataset
        #Load the csv file as a dataframe
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header=0, na_values='-')
        #Store the inputs and outputs
        self.x = df.values[:,:-2].astype('float32')
        self.y = df.values[:,1:].astype('float32')
        #Ensure target has the right shape
        self.y = self.y.reshape((len(self.y),2))

    def __len__(self):
        #Return the number of rows in the dataset
        return len(self.x)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #Return a row at an index
        return [self.x[idx], self.y[idx]]
```

Trainloader, loss, optimizer

```
dataset = TimeSeriesDataset('data.csv')
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

def lossFunc(outputs, labels):
  # nn.MSELoss() #Mean Squared Error, works fine with regression problems and with small numbers (x-y)^2
  return torch.mean((outputs-labels)**2)

net = Net()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.01)
print(net)
```

Trainning:

```
for epoch in range(300):

    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
        # TODO get the data
        # inputs, labels
        inputs, labels = data
        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # forward + backward + optimize
        outputs = net(inputs)
        #print("Inputs", inputs)
        #print("labels", labels)
        #print("outputs", outputs)
        loss = lossFunc(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        # print statistics
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 20 == 19:    # print every 20 mini-batches
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 20))
            running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Outputs looks this way:

```
tensor([[nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
        [nan, nan],
...
```

And when I execute the 300 epochs error value doesn't change and prints nan

Answer (score 1):

After the line `loss = loss(outputs, labels)`, loss is now a tensor, not a function anymore. Python does not allow you to have distinct objects with identical names.
So after the first call, `loss` has become a tensor, and as the error says "tensors are not callable", so the second call fails

Comment: All the implementatios I see call a custom loss function (Or predefined like nn.MSELoss) to get the error value and after that calls backwards. Can you write the correct implementation?

Comment: @Loren After your sneaky edit, which changed both the code and the error message, my answer is not relevant anymore. I don't see any particular wrongdoing in your implementation, so I think the problem comes from your data. Can you please post a minimal code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), maybe with a few particular tensors from your dataset that reproduce the problem ? Some of them may have weird values

Comment: The problem is that all the net outputs are ```tensor([[nan, nan],...])``` while the inputs and labels take good values, so for this reason I think that the loss doesn't change. My Net is a single Linear and the training doesn't crash at any point but for some reason doesn't work... The dataset is this: [dataset](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tmramalho/51733432c88e2b834dbd70353849f887/raw/676636d9e8512963005a318cb9b98060feadb641/data.csv) I just replaced '-' with nan.

Comment: Just to be sure : you feed the whole dataset (with the '-' as NaN) into your network, without sanitizing it (like removing the NaN) ? If yes, then no wonder, the NaN by definition are propagated through all arithmetic operations (whatever you do on a NaN, it yields a NaN)

Comment: Yes, I'm feeding the net with the whole dataset just replacing '-' with NaN. What kind of data sanitization do you recommend me?

Comment: I'd say, either you remove all the dataframes that contain a NaN (easier), or you interpolate : deducing their value from previous / next frames (smarter). Either way should give you a clean dataset (without NaN), and then you can feed it to your network. Dataset sanitization is a whole problem itself, so you may also want to read what internet can tell you  about it